# How can I manipulate GLM coefficients in R?

Tags: r

How can I manipulate a GLM object in order to bypass this error?  I would like for predict to treat the unseen levels as base cases (that is, give them a coefficient of zero.)

```
> master <- data.frame(x = factor(floor(runif(100,0,3)), labels=c("A","B","C")), y = rnorm(100))
> part.1 <- master[master$x == 'C',]
> part.2 <- master[master$x == 'A' | master$x == 'B',]
> model.2 <- glm(y ~ x, data=part.2)
> predict.1 <- predict(model.2, part.1)
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : factor 'x' has new level(s) C
```

I tried doing this:

```
> model.2$xlevels$x <- c(model.2$xlevels, "C")
> predict.1 <- predict(model.2, part.1)
```

But it's not scoring the model correctly:

```
> predict.1[1:5]
         2          3          6          8         10 
0.03701494 0.03701494 0.03701494 0.03701494 0.03701494 
> summary(model.2)

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ x, data = part.2)
<snip>
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  0.12743    0.18021   0.707    0.482
xB          -0.09042    0.23149  -0.391    0.697
```

predict.1 should only be 0.12743.

This is obviously just a trimmed down version--my real model has 25 or so variables in it, so an answer of `predict.1 <- rep(length(part.1), 0.12743)` is not useful to me.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hmm.  This is possible via hacking, but pretty tricky.  Can you give a bit more context?

Comment: Essentially I am building two separate predictive models depending on a covariate.  It would greatly simplify my scoring and evaluation code quite a bit if I could have those model predictions over the entire dataset, and not just the half they were modeled on.

Comment: what you are doing does not make sense. the data you are using to predict does not contain `x=C`. so there is no way you can use it to predict `y` for the case when `x=C`. it is like building a model of sales for weekdays and asking it to predict sales for the weekend. if you are looking to break the dataset into a calibration sample and validation sample, you need to do it such that both samples contain a similar distribution of the covariates.

Comment: You are focusing too much on the whys.   Suppose I know the coefficients from a prior study or model, and for some reason I can't offset them into the model?

Answer (score 1):

If you *know* that observations where x=='C' behave exactly like x=='A', then you can just do:

```
> part.1$x <- factor(rep("A",nrow(part.1)),levels=c("A","B"))
> predict(model.2, part.1)
```

which will give you your pure intercept model.

Comment: This seems like very much the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that you should expect any prediction. You develop a model with no items whose x variable is a factor whose value is "C" so you should not expect any prediction. Your effort to produce predictions for 1:5 also *should* fail.